# Can not get Transaction info from tron network

Tags: c#, blockchain, tron

I am using TronNet library to get transaction info by Id. My code looks like this

```cs
 public override async Task<TransactionData> GetTransactionDataAsync(string transactionId)
    {
        var transactionData = await _tronClient
            .GetWallet()
            .GetProtocol()
            .GetTransactionInfoByIdAsync(
                new BytesMessage
                {
                    Value = ByteString.CopyFromUtf8(transactionId)
                });

        return new TransactionData
        {
            TransactionId = transactionId,
            Fee = transactionData.Fee.ToString(),
            Status = transactionData.Result.ToString(),
            BlockHash = null,
            BlockNum = transactionData.BlockNumber.ToString(),
            TimeStamp = transactionData.BlockTimeStamp.ToString()
        };
    }
```

It gives me empty data all the time.

I use transaction hash as an Id: `e097d6d1215e9c04d9d9942db20c3f14fa2e9c417f8bc9737f173dc027ad469b`.

Is it wrong Id or am I passing the value in a wrong way ?